# NoClassDefFoundError for a AsyncTask

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I'm getting this weird `NoClassDefFoundError` exception on some devices only on a class that extends `AsyncTask`. The class in is my own project and not in a jar or library.

My compile jdk was set to 1.7 and I set it to 1.6 and problem still persists.

This happens on Samsung Tab 10 and HTC Sensation XL only. It works fine on Samsung S4, Note II and lots of other devices.

Any idea what could be causing this?

```
E/AndroidRuntime(4891): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(4891): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/***/***/networking/RequestExecutor
E/AndroidRuntime(4891):     at com.***.****t.ui.fragments.LoginFragment.handleLoginAction(LoginFragment.java:81)
E/AndroidRuntime(4891):     at com.****.****.ui.fragments.LoginFragment.onClick(LoginFragment.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(4891):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
E/AndroidRuntime(4891):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14400)
E/AndroidRuntime(4891):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
E/AndroidRuntime(4891):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(4891):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
E/AndroidRuntime(4891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
```

`RequestExecutor` is a class that extends AsyncTask

Comment: Could you please post a stacktrace?

Comment: updated the post with log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that the `Application` class of my app i was creating an `AsyncTask` in a background thread, which was messing up the rest of my `AsyncTask`s across the rest of the application.

Once i removed the creating of the `AsyncTask` to the UI thread, everything worked fine.